# How to get word between /

Tags: regex

How I can get a word between two **/**

```
http://www.amazon.fr/Les-cahiers-d%C3%A9criture-n%C2%BA1-Apprentissage/dp/221895608X/ref=zg_bs_3967461_1
```

With my regex `dp/.*?/` I get **dp/221895608X/** but I just want **221895608X**

Comment: Note that if you use negated class, i.e. `dp/([^/]*)/`, you get a boost in performance of about 30% compared to `dp/(.*?)/`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dp/(.*?)/` and then take the first group that matches, not the entire match.

**Note:** I can't tell you *how* to take the first matching group because you haven't specified which language you're using.

Comment: Well done :)
I use http://regexpal.com/ and he match dp/ with () so I just test on my script and it works.

Comment: @redeyes: OK, if you got the answer, feel free to Accept ;)

Comment: I can't accept your answer until 10 minutes, but don't worry I will give you +1.
thanks again

Comment: @redeyes: Actually, how can this work on `regexpal.com`? It just always shows the entire match.

Comment: @ErikAllik [see the highlighted part](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gi&regex=dp%2F%28.*%3F%29%2F&input=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.fr%2FLes-cahiers-d%25C3%25A9criture-n%25C2%25BA1-Apprentissage%2Fdp%2F221895608X%2Fref%3Dzg_bs_3967461_1)

Comment: @Prix: I'm only seeing a single yellow match... nothing separately for `(.+?)`.

Comment: @ErikAllik [Yes it doesn't show the group match only the result match in there, you could however use a different one like regex101.](http://regex101.com/r/wS5rG4)

Answer (score 2):

Sure - [positive lookaheads/lookbehinds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/(?<=\/dp\/).*?(?=\/)/
```

[**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/eD6jS8)

This will **only** match your string.

Autopsy:

- `(?<=\/dp\/)` - *A positive lookbehind that says that "the match has to have the string `/dp/` before it!"*
- `.*?` - *A lazy match - match as little as possible*
- `(?=\/)` - *A positive lookahead that says that "the match has to have the string `/` after it!"*

Comment: Have I missed something? Or does it really need to be that complex?

Comment: @ErikAllik It doesn't, but this would only match the string he wants (not necessarily in a capture group). It's to add upon your question to show that there's several ways of making this work.

Answer (score 0):

If it is JavaScript, you can use `split('/')` to get an array witrh those sub-strings

```
var str = 'http://www.amazon.fr/Les-cahiers-d%C3%A9criture-n%C2%BA1-Apprentissage/dp/221895608X/ref=zg_bs_3967461_1';
var arr_str = str.split('/');
var nrarrs = arr_str.length;
alert(arr_str[nrarrs - 2]);     // 221895608X
```

In PHP use `explode('/', $str)`